# How to write if-else condition in Python (Google App Engine)

Tags: html, django, google-app-engine, django-templates

I want to hide  `<li> Share: </li>` when the following three conditions are false or off. If any condition or all conditions are true then we will show   `<li> Share: </li>`

```
<ul>
   <li> Share: </li>
    {% ifequal g_share "on" %}  // condition 1
        // Div 
   {% endifequal %}

   {% ifequal fb_share "on" %} // condition 2
    // Div 
   {% endifequal %}

   {% ifequal tw_share "on" %} // condition 3
     //Div 
  {% endifequal %}
 </ul>
```

Can you tell me how to write if-else condition in python (Google app engine) to hide the 
`<li>`.

Comment: What template language is this? Jinja2? There is no Python code here.

Comment: this is google app engine code written in python

Comment: No, this is a template; it may be *called* by Python code, but this is a template language. If it is Jinja2 then it is based on Python, but it is *not the same thing*.

Comment: App Engine can use either Django or Jinja2 templates, depending on your app configuration https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates I suggest you first check which template language your app uses, then read the documentation for that template language. Also learn what Python is.

Comment: Sorry i really dont know :( . can u help me how to hide the li ?

Comment: I'd love to help you, but we are missing some crucial information here.

Comment: @Anentropic: Indeed, most likely this is Django; Jinja2 has no `ifequal` statement.

Comment: oh yes i just google it .. It's jinja2 language

Comment: No, this cannot be the Jinja2 language, because it doesn't have a `ifequal` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using [Django templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/), judging by the syntax.

Instead of `{% ifequal .. %}`, use the [`{% if ... %}` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#if) with the `==` operator, which lets you use boolean operators to combine tests:

```html
<ul>
   {% if g_share == "on" and fb_share == "on" and tw_share == "on" %}
      <li> Share: </li>
   {% endif %}
</ul>
```